# Check if tag, category or author on archive.php

Tags: theme-development

i'm making a wordpress theme and want to use a single archive.php page in order to present posts under a specific author, a category or tag. Now, i'm doing it like :

```
 if (is_author())
  {

  }

  if (is_category())
  {

  }

  if (is_tag())
  {

  }
```

I know i can divide this in more templates, but i don't want to repeat myself and i generally prefer to do it in a single php file. So, my question is :

How can i get either the category, tag or author in each of these ifs ? It seems that for the author i can use something like :

```
$author = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
```

and for the category :

```
get_query_var( 'cat');
```

But is this indeed the way to do it ? What is a safe way to get that information independent of permalinks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use it just like you posted which is safe and would do the job just fine:

```
if (is_author())
{
    $author = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
}

elseif (is_category())
{
    //this will work in categories tags or custom taxonomy
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
}

else(is_tag())
{
    //this will work in categories tags or custom taxonomy
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
}
```

Now after that as been said i would only recommend this way if this theme is not going to be released to the public and is for your own use, if this theme is to be released then i would divide my code  in to separate files for easier customization and keeping with theme structure standards.